# In flutter, how do I know who I sent text message to when I'm using share_plus library?

Tags: flutter, dart, share-plus

In flutter, how do I know who I sent text message to when I'm using share_plus library? I need the name of the text receiver and the phone number. Is this possible with share_plus? If it's not possible with share_plus, what can I do to achieve this?
Thanks

It seems like it doesn't return a handle for those info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if we are talking about sms messages, `share_plus` is not a suitable plug-in. If you want to get a message with sender information, you can try something like `flutter_sms_inbox`. Here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms_inbox) to the plug-in. If it doesn’t work well you might need to create your own implementation